# How to add onclick event to treeview in php(jquery plugin)?

Tags: php, treeview, events

I have realized a asynchronous [treeview](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-treeview/) in php, now i want to add onclick event to the items in the treeview, and then make query in mysql.

Do you know how to do that?

Thanks a lot.

Edit:

**Async.html:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#black").treeview({
        url: "twodimen.php"
    });
    $("#black > li").live("click",function()){
        $.get("");
    })
});
</script>

<ul id="black">
</ul>
```

But when i add the `$("#black > li").live("click", function()){}`, the treeview doesn't display.

How to do that?

Comment: Your treeview has the id='black', so try this instead: 

$("#black > li").click(function() { alert("CLICKED!!!"); } );

I also made an example, see here http://pastebin.com/m5f89e21b. I added an onClick event on the treenode for the first sample provided on the author website. Replace the alert() by you're Ajax call, using $.get() OR $.post(), not both ;)

Comment: @Racebacon, even i use $("#black > li").live("click",function()){}), the treeview doesn't display either. Only when i manually add a <li>sometext</li>, it pops up an alert. If i generate it from database, it doesn't display. Do you know why? I try to use $.get() or $post() .

Answer (score 1):

Well, this would be a start:

```
$("#treeview > li").click(function() { // this sets the onclick on your node
    $.get('url_to_php_script_that_will_the_db'); // this calls an url using GET.
    $.post('url_to_php_script_that_will_the_db'); // this calls an url using POST.
}
```

Suppose your treeview has id 'treeview', all the `<li>` under the treeview will have a click event. It's a rough start, but that's basically what you're looking for.

Comment: @Racebacon, please see my edit. I've changed my code, but i don't know how to do the following things.

Comment: Can you post your entire treeview code? From what I see, it's probably the 'ul > li' selector that conflicts, but i'd need more insight.